# Passagem de informações entre páginas

Tags: php, mysql, session

Qual a melhor forma pra passar informações (dados) entre as páginas?

Exemplo:

Tenho 4(quatro) páginas `dadospessoais.php`, `endereco.php`, `habilitacoes.php` e `salvar.php`.

Nas páginas (`dadospessoais.php`, `endereço.php` e `habilitacoes.php`) receberão os dados do usuário através de formulários, nestas páginas consigo avançar para a próxima e consigo retroceder, lembrando que ao retroceder consigo recuperar os dados inseridos pelo usuário.

A página `salvar.php` receberá todos os dados das 3 (três) páginas e salvará as informações em um banco de dados.

Gostaria de saber em relação a performance da aplicação e principalmente do SERVIDOR, qual a melhor forma de se trabalhar com a passagem destas informações, lembrando que a página será acessada em média por 100 a 200 usuários/dia podendo se ter um número de acesso maior. Atualmente trabalho com SESSION guardando todos os dados dos usuários em uma SESSION e os recuperando da mesma forma, porém não sei se esta forma é a mais aconselhável, pois tenho notado uma lentidão na aplicação e algumas falhas quando tento salvar os dados no banco de dados.

Já vi comentários que mantendo muitas sessões abertas no servidor poderia haver uma perda de performance, inclusive sobrecarregar o servidor, não sei ao certo como funciona, mas todas as sessões que são abertas o conteúdo é salvo, dependendo do servidor, na pasta tmp. Fico imaginando muitos acessos ao site e cada dado de cada usuário logado (nome, email, telefone, endereço, habilitada etc) sendo salvos no servidor, é por isso que questionei se haveria outra forma, ou se utilizam outras formas nas aplicações.

Comment: Session não é bom para isso por outro motivo: não dá pra fazer duas operações ao mesmo tempo em abas separadas sem conflito (por exemplo, começo o cadastro do Francisco na primeira aba, e o da Francisca na segunda aba, um vai sobrepor o outro). Um caminho seria usar campos _hidden_ passados entre as páginas, ou armazenar num DB temporário e passar ao menos o ID da ficha ao voltar e avançar (neste caso, tendo um _array_ dá pra usar _session_ da mesma forma, passando um ID entre as páginas pra que uma aba fique independente da outra).

Comment: todos os dados? poxa, guarda só uma referencia dele, só o mais importante, o resto tu pega do banco quando precisar

Comment: Bacco, entendi em relação ao uso das abas e ao hidden também, agora com relação ao DB temporário, não sei se compreendi direito, mas eu teria que salvar os dados de cadas etapa em database temporário? E quando fosse voltar a página eu recuperaria os dados neste banco temporário, e no final de todo o cadastro eu salvaria todos os dados no DB seria isso? Em relação a performance no servidor entre as duas opções que forneceu seria melhor então usar hidden, tendo em vista a performance no servidor, com as requisições ao banco de dados?

Comment: RodrigoBorth não entendi muito bem o que quis me dizer, em se tratando de formulário de cadastro divididos em 3(três) páginas, sendo que o usuário consegue avançar e voltar nas páginas e recuperar também os dados inseridos, você diz por exemplo, o usuário preenche a 1ª pág e guardo parte da informação em um banco?

Comment: @GuilhermeQuinalia quase todos os SGBDs convencionais tem tabelas temporárias e até mesmo de memória (o _session_ também equivale a um DB). Se sua aplicação vai girar em torno de milhares de usuários cadastrando coisas ao mesmo tempo, acho que dá pra se preocupar com performance, senão, é besteira. Campo hidden aumenta o tráfego entre as páginas, DB usa mais espaço no servidor. Mas as quantidades sao tão ínfimas, nos dois casos, que eu acho que o trabalho que dá pra economizar um punhado de bytes sai mais caro que o benefício.

Comment: Dependendo do que for feito, pode usar as [*tabs do bootstrap*](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs), para agrupar os campos por 'assunto' e um *save* para dar um update no que foi alterado. Assim mantém os dados na mesma página sem tráfego.

Comment: Muito obrigado Bacco! Papa Charlie acredito que as tabs se encaixariam bem no meu caso, já que quero dividir por "assuntos", "conteúdos" somente para o usuário, pra dar ao mesmo usabilidade e facilidade no preenchimento dos dados, evitando que o mesmo permaneça na mesma página preenchendo muitos campos, com o tab consigo simular o progresso do cadastro ao usuário e não preciso utilizar session para gravar os dados e nem mesmo hidden ou db já que estarei na mesma página. Obrigado pessoal!